# Не работает индексация по составному первичному ключу

Tags: mysql, index

Есть следующая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `MCA_calls` (
  `date_time_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `call_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `calling_number` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `called_number` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`call_id`,`calling_number`,`called_number`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_time_created` (`date_time_created`),
  KEY `called_number` (`called_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Делаю **`EXPLAIN`** по запросу типа, и вижу что индекс не подтягивается, если вешаю обычный индекс на поле **`called_number`** то все ок

```
mysql> EXPLAIN DELETE FROM MCA_calls WHERE called_number = 123456789;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | MCA_calls | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 192014 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: В первичном ключе `called_number` не является префиксом - поэтому первичный индекс не может быть использован в указанном запросе.

Comment: То есть если первым поле в состановм ключе указать именно called_number идекс сработает?

Comment: здесь  сработает, зато в другом месте потеряете мб.

Comment: Да поставил первым поле called_number, действительно отработало. Ну мне по сути больше ничего и не нужно, это поле ключевое в моих запросах, а использовал соствной первичный вместо id инкремента, так как эта таблица постоянно инсертится и удаляется, поэтому не хочу чтобы айди нарастал сильно

Comment: Индекс он как отсортированный словарь, представьте что вы телефонный справочник отсортировали по фамилии и потом по имени (внутри каждой фамилии),  а теперь его пытаетесь листать что бы найти всех "Олег". Вам как бы его весь пролистать и придется. А вот если бы по фамилии искали сначала "Иванов", то быстро бы нужную страницу нашли и в пределах нее нашли бы уже Олегов Ивановых. БД делает с индексом абсолютно так же, какое первое поле в индексе по тому и надо искать в первую очередь

Comment: @Mike Спасибо очень доходчиво, вроде с  пониманием индексов никогда проблем не было, а вот участие префикса в составном не знал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс он как отсортированный словарь, представьте что вы телефонный справочник отсортировали по фамилии и потом по имени (внутри каждой фамилии), а теперь пытаетесь  найти всех "Олег". Вам как бы его весь пролистать и придется. А вот если бы по фамилии искали сначала "Иванов", то быстро бы нужную страницу нашли и в пределах нее нашли бы уже Олегов Ивановых. БД делает с индексом абсолютно так же, какое первое поле в индексе по тому и надо искать в первую очередь.

Соответственно вам надо поставить первым полем в индексе called_number, если чаще всего ищете по нему.

Так же давайте рассмотрим ситуацию с справочником отсортированным по году рождения и фамилии. При выполнении поиска по диапазону лет, ищем Ивановых с 1980 по 1990 годы рождения. Если год на первом месте, нам придется по очереди открыть страницы каждого года и там поискать блок Ивановых. По этому при наличии полей с поиском по диапазону их лучше размещать ближе к концу ключа, а выносить на первое место поля с поиском по точному совпадению.